# Document is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: itext

```
try {
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Report.pdf"));
  document.open();
  document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
  document.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

This is the code  i have written in NetBeans but i am getting error in first line:

```
error 1 in 1st line: Document is abstract; cannot be instantiated 

error 2 in 2nd line cannot find symbol ,symbol: variable PdfWriter
```

Comment: Is the class PdfWriter provided by third party jars,or by yourself?

Comment: PdfWriter is provided by 3rd party jars

Comment: So there are two problems! First,check whether the 3rd party jars are in the classpath while compiling your code. Second,check the API the class Document to see how to create new document,I guess the object should be created by some Factory-like class .

Answer (score 7):

You are clearly importing the wrong `Document` class, the correct import is [com.itextpdf.text.Document](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html), update your import statements and this will be fixed.

Comment: How i can import com.itextpdf.text.Document ?

Comment: Look at http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12 Can you see the lines import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter; (Additionally: have you aver written a Java application?)

Comment: when i am i porting these header files it's again give error in import line (in import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
) itself. I got this error : Unused Import

Comment: You should post your complete source file as it seems to be cluttered with issues.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem, you have to copy and paste this import statement: 
it will work 100%
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;

Answer (score 1):

**Download itext-5.1.3** it will work 100% sure . :) and **add all the JAR into your project .**
I faced the same problem and solved it.

Comment: This won't do any good. First of all, as the other answers mention, the op has to use the correct `Document` class, e.g. by importing it. And if one advises a re-download of the library, one should recommend a current version (as of now at least 5.5.10), not an ancient one.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove**

`import javax.swing.text.Document;`

and **add**

`import com.itextpdf.text.Document;`