# Why does the Document class give an error when I try to initialize it?

Tags: android

When I write this line of code:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

Then `new Document()` becomes red and shows an error which is

> document is abstract cannot be instantiated.

What can I do now to solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998549/document-is-abstract-cannot-be-instantiated

Comment: I check it but problem not solve

Comment: Please add the entire code that you are using, not only the instantiation of an object.

Comment: i inport iTextpdf-5.1.3.jar in libs and add implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10' depedency. and don't write whole code only write this line    Document document = new Document();    only

Comment: when i write this line it give error so i stop and search about it

Comment: it underline new document() with red color

Comment: and when i press alt+ enter it give lot of methods

Comment: please send me the exact link from i download itext jar

Comment: @Patrick you lost a LOT of information with that edit. Be careful when you edit code

Comment: @AmmaraRasheed Document is abstract, which means you need to initialize or create a subclass of it before you use it.

Comment: Hi am working on place autocomplete suggetion but i dont found place sdk for androd api update  om console and now only place api present on console i enabke it but get error places api accesss not configure plz help me plz